Horror movie or movie with short horror stories, where few, maybe four people enter some (abandoned?) mansion
And then they get separated and are looking for each other. Only thing beyond that I can remember is one scene, where one of the guys is like "hanging" under a green light bulb in empty room, it seems that he is somehow "captured" by the light bulb?? Movie is from late 70's, 80's or early 90's.

It's a long shot, but the film Mr. Boogedy? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Boogedy


Screams of a Winter Night (1979)

A vanload of young people heads out to a cabin on Lake Durand. Once they get there, these ten students tell scary stories to each other.


One reviewer lists out the three spooky tales:


The first story, entitled "The Moss Point Man", is a combination of the Big Foot legend and the urban legend known as the Lover's Lane
  Killer; nothing too special. 
The second story, entitled "The Green Light", deals with three fraternity pledges who are dared to spend the night in a haunted
  hotel, where supposedly a mysterious green light is emitted from
  somewhere on the upper floors.
The third and final story, entitled "Crazy Annie" or "The Girl Next Door" (I'm not entirely sure what the title of the story is), is about
  a mousy, sexually repressed college girl who becomes a psychotic
  killer after almost being raped.

And all around these stories is the wraparound story with the college
  kids and some sort of Native American wind spirit that dwells within
  the forest.


~ Screenshots taken from The Bloody Pit of Horror
Read more about the movie here and here. Watch that climactic scene from the second segment here.

That's the one, thank you very much :-)
